# How to add dependency installations to product.wxs in wix setup

Tags: xml, wix, windows-installer

I have created wix setup and for my application to work correctly i need to install .net framework 4.5 according to the documentation that can be done using burn using a bundle i'm confused how I should link product.wxs with a bundle do i have to create separate project for the bundle.Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you mention "project," you must be using Visual Studio to edit your WiX sources, manage your WiX tool command-line options and build your WiX outputs. That might seem obvious to you but you have to understand that the WiX documentation generally focuses on calling the WiX tools directly. Just like with most Visual Studio project types (e.g., C# Library, VB .NET Console Application), the build process ultimately does call command-line tools that you could call yourself.

That said, the documentation is a bit lagging on the use of Visual Studio. To create a burn project, use the WiX Bootstrapper Project template. A burn project has nothing to do with a product.wxs; It has a bundle.wxs. (The filenames don't matter, the root element of the XML files do.)

Since you want to install your MSI and it is created from a WiX project, you might want both projects in one solution and add the MSI project as a reference to the burn project. See [Using Project References and Variables](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/votive/votive_project_references.html).

Now you can use the documentation for [Install the .NET Framework Using Burn](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/howtos/redistributables_and_install_checks/install_dotnet.html), [Chain Packages into a Bundle](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/bundle/bundle_author_chain.html) and [MsiPackage Element](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/xsd/wix/msipackage.html).

Answer (score -1):

Have you looked at [this well known Wix-tutorial](http://wix.tramontana.co.hu/node/76) for the basics of how this is done?